# Button setting DialogResult automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have overridden the default `ShowDialog()` method on this form with this:

```
    public DialogResult ShowDialog(int itemToEdit) 
    {
        this._itemToEdit = itemToEdit;
        FillForm(Program.AppConfig.Tweets[itemToEdit]);
        return this.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The form has an "OK" and a "Cancel" button whose click handlers look like this:

```
    private void cancelButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
```

However, I have another button which does **not** set the `DialogResult` property of the form, yet when it is clicked it is somehow set, and the form hides, returning `DialogResult.Cancel`. I do not want this to be happening.

Edit: Actually, every button in the form makes it return `DialogResult.Cancel`, regardless of whether it has a `Click` handler or not.

Comment: Check the properties of this button (in design mode). Does it have `DialogResult` set to `None`?

Comment: You need to close your question, it was answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check `DialogResult` property of that button. It should be `None`. And make sure that the button Click event is not set to `cancelButton_Click`

Comment: D'oh! I copied and pasted the buttons in the form, and the DialogResult property must've stayed the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check the [CancelButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.cancelbutton%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-property of the form. For the button that is assigned to this property, the DialogResult is set automatically (similar to the AcceptButton property).

Also check the [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the other button. It might be set to DialogResult.Cancel and by that close the form and return the DialogResult you observe.